# Why throw the error of "Cannot add content to an object of type" by customcontrol?

Tags: wpf

I wrote a customcontrol inhert `Control` and add a DependencyProperty `content` which I want it to be the same as the `content`  of the button control.

Here is the code:

```
[System.ComponentModel.Bindable(true)]
public object Content
{
    get { return (object)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Content.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Content", typeof(object), typeof(SContent), null);
```

But after I reference the dll and run the program, WPF threw this error:
[image]
[image]

What's wrong with this? Would you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Did you decorate your class with a `[ContentProperty("Content")]` attribute?

Comment: You should probably make your `SContent` control inherit from `ContentControl`. (ContentControl already provides a `Content` property and the necessary attribute metadata, so you don't need to recreate/reimplement this property from scratch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your custom control to support direct content in XAML, you should decorate it with the [ContentPropertyAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) :

```
[ContentProperty("Content")]
public class SContent : Control
{
    [System.ComponentModel.Bindable(true)]
    public object Content
    {
        get { return GetValue(ContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Content), typeof(object), typeof(SContent), null);
}
```

But if you just want a `Content` property you might as well inherit from `ContentControl` instead of `Control`. Then you also get a `ContentTemplate` property and some other stuff "for free".